# BackboneJS + RequireJS: Undefined is not a function

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I'm trying to implement RequireJS in my project and am running into some problems. I'm getting an error is my Item model. In the model, I'm trying to set an attribute to a new collection. In that line I get the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function."

My router looks something like this:

```
define(['backbone', 'collections/items', 'views/itemsView'], function (Backbone, Items, ItemsView) {
  var Workspace = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      '*path': 'nearby'
    },

    nearby: function() {
      var items = new Items();
      items.fetch();
      var itemsView = new ItemsView({
         collection: items
      });
  });
  return Workspace;
});
```

Collection:

```
define(['backbone', 'models/item', 'tastypie'], function(Backbone, Item) {
  var Items = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    url: function() {
      var url;
      url = '/api/v1/nearby/?lat=' + lat1 + '&lng=' + lon1;
      return url;
    },

    model: Item,

  });
  return Items;
});
```

Model:

```
define(['backbone', 'collections/locations'], function (Backbone, Locations) {
  var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/api/v1/item',

    url: function () {
      // stuff here
    },

    set: function (attrs) {
      // Making a new Locations collection ordered by distance
      if (attrs.items && attrs.items.length > 0) {
        // Sets the collection as an attrubute
        // The following line is where I get the error
        attrs.locations = new Locations(attrs.items);
        Backbone.Model.prototype.set.apply(this, [attrs]);

        // Sets the closest attribute
        attrs.closest = this.get('locations').getClosestItem().get('distance');
        Backbone.Model.prototype.set.apply(this, [attrs]);
        attrs.numItems = this.get('items').length;
        Backbone.Model.prototype.set.apply(this, [attrs]);
      }
      return Backbone.Model.prototype.set.apply(this, [attrs]);
    },

  });
  return Item;
});
```

Anyone know why I'm getting the error? I made sure to define to Location collection in my model.

edit: adding in the locations.js file:

```
define(['backbone', 'models/location'], function (Backbone, LocationModel) {
  var Locations = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: LocationModel,

    comparator: function(item) {
      return item.get('distance') + ' ' + item.get('name');
    },

    getClosestItem: function() {
      return this.at(0);
    }
  });
  return Locations;
});
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: In my model, I tried logging Locations to the console but it comes back as undefined. I can console log Bacbkbone just fine. I looked at my Locations collection and it all looks normal to me.

Comment: I don't. Not quite sure how to do that. I didn't think I had to put underscore in there. I just tried but still not working. I do have jquery and underscore as dependents for backbone when setting up my require config. I can console.log($) and _ in the model and it works.

Comment: Underscore is a requirement of Backbone.  You have to shim it in or use lodash.  The function it can't find is probably one of the underscore functions.

Comment: I am using a shim. I can console.log the collection in my router, but for some reason it won't work in my model.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function item.js:21
Backbone.Model.extend.set item.js:21
Backbone.Model backbone.js:254
child backbone.js:1541
_.extend._prepareModel backbone.js:913
_.extend.set backbone.js:700
options.success backbone.js:860
l jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4
c.fireWith jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4
k jquery-2.0.3.min.js:6
(anonymous function)

Comment: I can't figure out why the collection is undefined when I try to console.log(Locations), especially when I can do it in my router. Maybe that's the real problem.

Comment: You'll need to include locations.js too as the problem is probably its return value. Also, remember to clearly mark the place the error happens in your (future) questions, for example with a comment "Error happens in the following line"; try to help people trying to help you.

Comment: In your model you define `Item`, but `return Beer`.

Comment: Damn, that didn't do it either. I am including the Location model in the Locations collection btw.

Comment: Oh yea... I'm actually doing this with beer not "items." I'm returning the right stuff, just didn't catch that when changing it here.

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo, remember, the module names are **case sensitive**. example if you require `collections/locations` and your file name is `collections/Locations.js` it won't work. Or: In your previous comment, you said, you can require it in your router, but there you include `collections/items`, but in the model you try to require `collections/locations`.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand what you're saying at the end there, balazs.

Comment: In one of your comments, you said you can see your collection in your router, where you refer to it as `collections/items`, but in your model you refer to a file `collections/locations`.

Comment: Oh I see. If I make sure to include the locations collection in the router and model, I can only see it in the router.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44115/discussion-between-balazs-and-ukejoe)

Comment: @balazs wrong filename (e.g. wrong caps) would result in an 404, not *'Undefined is not a function'* when calling `new Locations(...)`. Without OP posting code for collections/locations.js there's nothing more we can do.

Comment: Added my locations.js

Comment: Can we see your Locations model definition? I noticed that you require it for your Locations collection. (eg. 'models/location')